# android - get those contacts who have the same custom account

Tags: android

Every user in my app first needs to signup / login and therefore authenticate with the server using the AccountManager and AccountAuthenticator. On sccessful authentication an account of type *tld.mypackage.name.account* is created on the device.

What I want to do now is get a list of exactly these contacts from my address book who have the same type of account associated with their mobile number, e.g. as it's done in WhatsApp - I want a subset of all my contacts who are registered for my app.

What is the right way to do this? Does Google have kind of a list of all android users and their account types in AccountManager or sth. similar I can use sync? Or do I have to implement an own syncing with my server, e.g. sending my whole contacts' phone numbers to my server and get back a list of those, who the server is aware of?

Comment: sorry but: *I have to implement an own syncing with my server* is a good answer

Comment: Using the Android SyncAdapter: http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html ?
What does it do?

Comment: it is a good example how to store your account type contacts and sync them with server ... but for checking/matching you need to build another webservice which will take fx `[ {"id": "contactId1",  "phone": "number1"}, {"id": "contactId2",  "phone": "number2"}, ... ]` json and returns `[{"id": "contactId1", "found" : true, "name": "xxx xxx"}, {"id": "contactId2", "found" : false }, ... }]` ... then proces it on android

Comment: Thanks. I already have a restful webservice written in Node.js, it won't be too much effort to extend it to do the user matching.
But what would be the better way: Writing an own SyncAdapter or simply do a little request from within my app, e.g. on every start? Or in other words, what would be the benefit of reading up on the subject of the SyncAdapters?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question.
This guy has a very nice blog post on how to use SyncAdapter's and their benefits: https://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/

- Battery efficiency – The system schedules the sync to run when other
  syncs run, or when some other network request was already made on the
  device. This prevents awaking the device from its sleep for
  performing a single sync.
- Interface – All sync adapter on the device can be accessed from the
  Settings screen, under the account they are tied to. This gives the
  end user the option to change sync preferences, see if there are any
  sync problem or even disable the sync.
- Content awareness – If we use ContentProvider for
  accessing/manipulating our data, the sync adapter can observe any
  changes done to it. That way it can run only when the data actually
  changes.
- Retry mechanism – The sync manager has its implementation to retry
  failed syncs, using timeouts and exponential back offs. All those to
  conserve battery and sync your data as soon as possible.